# Deploying Kurento-media-server on GCP

Tags: kurento

We built a web conferencing app in which a custom filter is applied on the host of the meeting.We built the client using Java(Springboot) by following the kurento documentation.We built our own docker image that consists of the filter built using opencv.We run the docker image to apply the filter and run the kms pipeline.

The app runs fine on localhost. We are trying to deploy the app on a GCP instance. We created an Ubuntu instance and also installed coturn. We have configured a turn server .But when we run the app on the gcp instance, we are unable to stream the video to the web browser. We have opened all udp ports on gcp and required tcp ports on the vm instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure working coTURN server.
If possible create your own TURN server on the cloud instance using a domain name.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm